# How to navigate from one popup to another

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a popup which is

```
function validateDropDown(obj){   
 if(document.getElementById(obj).value=='4')   
 {    alert('Do you want to view Service Details?');    
 return false;   
 }   
 }
```

Now, when the popup asks "Do you want to view Service Details?" and if i give OK, then it should take me to the other page. Please help me how to incorporate this,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return true if you want `postback`, use confirm instead of `alert` to get user choice. `confirm` will return true for yes and false other wise. If you want to open new page then use [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function.

```
function validateDropDown(obj){   
  if(document.getElementById(obj).value=='4')   
  {   
      choice = confirm('Do you want to view Service Details?'); 
      if(choice)
         window.open("http://somesite/newWindow.aspx", "_blank", "height=500, width=575, left=150,top=150, " +"location=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, " + "scrollbars=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no", true);   
      return false;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. Can you please say me how to navigate to the other page as well? If i give OK, it should navigate to some other website page. Please help.

Comment: You have to give url in first parameter of window.open, check my updated answer.